# linux get specific fields from several files

Tags: linux, file, get, field

I have several files starting with the string "file" then a number (file1, file2, etc).

The content of these files is similar and looks like this

```
file1:
$xx_ at 10.0 "$elt_(0) coordinates 636.46 1800.37 9.90"
$xx_ at 10.0 "$elt_(1) coordinates 367.78 1263.63 7.90"
```

For each file, I want only keep the index of the element and the 2 numeric fields just after coordinates (in the same file or in another file):

file1:

```
0  636.46 1800.37 
1 367.78 1263.63
```

What I tried to do is like this (but It is not correct)

```
find . -name "file*"|while read fname; do
  echo "$fname"
  for line in $(cat "$fname") do
   FS="[_() ]"
   print   $7 "\t" $10 "\t" $11 > $fname
  done
done
```

Comment: Is the number in `$elt_(0)` the same as the index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the perfect use of awk.
With awk you can simply print specific words.

If the index is the line number you can use this:

`cat -n ./file1 | awk '{print $1 -1 " " $7 " " $8}'` this simply prints the files with line numbers and prints the first, seventh and eighth word.

If the index is the `$elt_(0)` number in parenthese you can use sed like this:

```
cat ./file1 | awk '{print $4 " " $7 " " $8}' | sed 's/"$elt_(//g' | sed 's/)//g' | sed 's/"//g'
```

output:

```
1 636.46 1800.37
2 367.78 1263.63
```

[Link to awk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK)
[Link to sed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed)

Comment: I tried with awk, I can do it for a single file but not in a loop. Because I have several files so can't do it one by one.

Comment: What is the index?

Comment: What about `find -type f -iname "*file-pattern*" -exec script.sh {}\;` script.sh is this awk-stuff in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.